# Selecting oldest data first

Tags: mysql

i want to select info which was registered in database earlier first one by one,

its i want to select oldest info first then newer, like to be in order (first come first serve) one by one

like

Today - some info

Yesterday - some info

day before yesterday - some info

```
SELECT info FROM table ORDER BY A DESC LIMIT 1
```

table

```
id info date_registered 
1  john 9999-12-31 23:59:59
```

Comment: Your description is rather unclear. Please add more rows to your sample data, and also show us the result that you want.

Comment: the question is clear, 

i want to select info which was registered in database earlier first one by one,

its i want to select oldest info first then newer, like to be in order (first come first serve) one by one - my try query   SELECT info FROM table ORDER BY A DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: i dont think there something confusing there

Comment: i just want query to select oldest info first and then newer later one by one in order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is vague, but there's various ways you can do it.

What are you doing with this?

1. check out OFFSET and LIMIT, which you'd do something like run your query and then increase the offset each time you run it.
2. just use whatever programming language you're using to loop over the result set? IE remove the limit.
3. 3 it multiple times and add a where clause which uses the previous return value.

```
SELECT info 
FROM table 
where date_registered < '9999-12-31' 
order by date_registered desc 
limit 1
```